# Is it possible to support drag and drop to from Photos app in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I have a simple app with a single ViewController `UIViewController` subclass that has a `UICollectionView` subview. I'd like to be able to drag images and video from the photos app onto my collectionView, but none of the `UICollectionViewDropDelegate` functions are being called when I drop them on the collectionView, the images simply disappear as though the drop was cancelled. Am I missing a step somewhere? I haven't been able to find any examples of dragging from the photos app anywhere. I've set the collectionView's `dropDelegate` property to the `ViewController`, and verified that the `ViewController` in fact the `dropDelegate`, but nothing has worked so far. Here's the code I have so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var images = [UIImage]()

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.dropDelegate = self
    }
}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ImageCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
        cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDropDelegate
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDropDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        // breakpoint
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        let types = [kUTTypeJPEG, kUTTypeTIFF, kUTTypePNG, kUTTypeQuickTimeMovie, kUTTypeMPEG4] as [String]
        return session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: types) && session.items.count == 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidEnter session: UIDropSession) {
        // breakpoint
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidExit session: UIDropSession) {
        // breakpoint
    }
}
```

Comment: according to documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_collection_views you also should implement drag delegate methods

Comment: Isn't that only necessary if you're dragging from the same collectionView? I'm trying to drag from the Photos app, not my own app's collectionViews. Either way, there's something else going on, as the drag delegate functions aren't being called either

Comment: I recently added support for dragging photos into my table view and I am able to drag photos from the Photos app onto my table view. I only needed to implement 3 of the DropDelegate methods to make it work. I implemented the first three (but the table view versions in my case) that you have in your question. Is the `canHandle` delegate being called at all?

Comment: I did just barely get it to call `canHandle`, but only if I dragged from the full photos app (not in slide over view). I'm using an iPad mini, so I assume that trying to drag from slide over view wouldn't work because it's essentially running as if it were an iPhone, so it would only be able to drag in the same app...? I'm just throwing out ideas here. I don't have an iPad pro to test my theory and I've had trouble getting and app into split view in the simulator, not to mention simulating dragging multiple photos in the simulator